# hey i want a copy from my projects saved in my documents to copy to the removable disk does it possible in vb.net form

Tags: vb.net

hi i am mukesh i want a form were i have a button now i want to copy what ever i still now changes made in a vb.net from to be stored inside the pendrive just by clicking on the button does it possible

i have done a project which is a shops project now my client wants to do that project when he is in shop he will use it in laptop
 but when he moves to some other location he wants to carry that project in a pendrive since he is not so much educated o he needs only one key which he must press to copy the database from my source my documents to the pendrive does it possible

Comment: Tell your client to buy a file server.  Databases don't belong on pen drives nor should ever be copied for any other purpose than backup.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need for portability of a vb.net project. It doesn't work well to be working off of removable media (such as a pen drive) for vb.net projects. What you will want to do is copy the directory for your project onto the pendrive for storage only. When you/your client wants to work on the project, you will need to copy it to the hard drive of whatever computer you're working on before opening it in Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you use).

Furthermore, if you're working with a database, it cannot be run off of removable media. So, again, same solution.

As to wanting to copy your files using a form...while plausible in theory, it isn't really practical for the sheer mass of code you would have to have. You'd have to compensate for an number of situations, and in the end, you'd waste more time than you would save your client. Standard copy and paste in Windows Explorer is pretty simple, so perhaps you could show your client how to do that.

Hope that helps!